# "Nullable object must have a value" exception in my Linq query after using safe navigation operator

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ expression:

```
results = siteVisits.Select(r => new OnSiteRecordModel { 
                        Hours = r.TimeOnSite?.TotalHours, 
                        OnsiteSATime = r.WorkStartTime?.UtcDateTime,
                        ResourceAssignmentStatusId = r.ResourceAssignmentStatusId });
```

As you can see, I am using safe navigation operator. I have no issues debugging the code in my local instance. But when this code is in production, I am seeing the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.
```

The properties in OnSiteRecordModel class are all nullable. I would like to understand why I am getting the above error. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is it *LinqToSql*? If yes then you might not want to use *Null Propagation Operator*

Comment: You might have to use ternary operator if it is linq to sql
`Hours = r.TimeOnSite != null ? r.TimeOnSite.TotalHours : (int?) null`